# Remove contents between script and style tags in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, tags, download

Alright, so I am working on a web crawler that can take webpages and convert them into passages of text. To remove the tags themselves, I found this on Stack Overflow:

```
- (NSString *) stripTags:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *ms = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
    NSString *s = nil;
    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&s];
        if (s != nil)
            [ms appendString:s];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];
        if (![scanner isAtEnd])
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
        s = nil;
    }

    return ms;
}
```

And it works, however, it only removes the *tags*, not the contents between script and style tags (as obviously I don't want the contents between all tags to be removed as that would result in an empty string).

Is there any way I can have specifically the script and style tags truncated?

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:

I have tried changing my code to:

```
- (NSString *) stripTags:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *ms = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
    NSString *s = nil;
    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<script" intoString:&s];
        if (s != nil)
            [ms appendString:s];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"script>" intoString:NULL];
        if (![scanner isAtEnd])
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&s];
        if (s != nil)
            [ms appendString:s];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];
        if (![scanner isAtEnd])
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
        s = nil;
    }

    return ms;
}
```

but the scripts and css is still being included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the scanner code so that you can check the tags. If the tag is one you want to remove then you can scan to the closing tag and just discard the string. You not then you can store / append the string.

---

Read up to the tag start (`<`)' then read the tag so you can check what it is. Then read to the tag close and either drop it or save it.

---

Start with something like (typed inline and not tested in any way):

```
while (![scanner isAtEnd])
{
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&s];
    if (s != nil)
        [ms appendString:s];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&t];
    if ([t isEqualToString:@"tagToIgnore"]) {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]-1];
        s = nil;
        t = nil;
        continue;
    }
    if (![scanner isAtEnd])
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
    s = nil;
    t = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean but how will I ensure that the other tags are removed and that the scripts and css content is removed?

Comment: By the construction of your `if` statement checks. You have an `if / else` and in one condition your dropping the content and in the other you're saving.

Comment: I've tried running it through a second method: `- (NSString *) stripJS:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *ms = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];
    
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
    NSString *s = nil;
    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<script" intoString:&s];
   if (s != nil) [ms appendString:s];
      [scanner scanUpToString:@"script>" intoString:NULL];
if (![scanner isAtEnd])
     [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
 s = nil;}
    return ms;
}`

Comment: So you're trying to remove the script and then process the remainder? That won't work very well with nested tags...

Comment: yeah… well I'm pretty new to this so I'm just experimenting :) I'm really not sure the best way to implement this.

Comment: You need to process it one tag at a time and decide what to do for each. Don't search for `<script` as you'll read past content you want to process.

Comment: Well, how would I do that? I'm kind of lost I'm sorry if I look incompetent.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but after trying this, it still doesn't work. It removes the script tag but not the contents of the script itself.

Comment: Did you debug to check what tags are being process and replace `tagToIgnore` with the correct tag name (probably `<script`)?

Comment: yep, I did, it removes the tag but not the content itself of the tag. thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it run `[scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];`? You will need to debug and tweak / add to the above, it's just the starting point.

Comment: thanks for the help, I'll take that code as a starting and work forward! Thanks again!